# code push updates doesn't arrive to the application

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, code-push

i'm working on application using ionic 4 so i try to use code-push-plugin to release updates to my app.
 i setup the plugin correctly and i manage to upload updates using cli to the app center but when i try to open my application nothing happens.

I use "ionic cordova build android" to generate the apk 
to test it in a real device

and "code-push release-cordova K4A android" to release the updates

i check the appcenter and go to staging releases and i found my releases updates

here's my code in home.page.ts

```
constructor( private codePush: CodePush, private platform: Platform
    ) {
this.platform.ready().then(()=> {
  this.codePush.sync({}, (progress)=> {

  }).subscribe((status) => {
   if (status == SyncStatus.CHECKING_FOR_UPDATE)
   alert("Checking for updates");
   if (status == SyncStatus.DOWNLOADING_PACKAGE)
   alert("Downloading");
   if (status == SyncStatus.IN_PROGRESS)
   alert("in progress");
   if (status == SyncStatus.INSTALLING_UPDATE)
   alert("installing the updates ...");
   if (status == SyncStatus.UPDATE_INSTALLED)
   alert("update installed");
   if (status == SyncStatus.ERROR)
   alert("Error");
  })
})
```

and this is the config.xml

```
widget id="com.KO4A.KORA" version="0.0.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="CodePushDeploymentKey" value="TM8jRvULboCjSVhDzApTk6Yu7Kry97c78f7d-6a98-4378-a263-abd88ec58996" />
    </platform>
    <name>K4A</name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most tipical issue is broken deployment key. Check that it is the same as in portal(or get it with cli).
If it is correct, provide logs during update? Logs should contains more info.